# How to copy a csv file from google cloud storage to specific google drive folder?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to copy files over from my google cloud storage bucket to a specific google drive folder based on a `object.finalized` cloud function trigger. This is the python code I've created in the google cloud inline editor below

```
import functions_framework
import base64
import tempfile
import traceback
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def upload_to_drive(temp_file, remote_path, credentials):
    """Uploads a file to the specified folder in Google Drive.

    Args:
        temp_file (tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile): Temporary file object containing the data to upload.
        remote_path (str): Name of the file to be created in Google Drive.
        credentials (google.auth.credentials.Credentials): Authentication credentials.
    """
    folder_id = str("1nNqtRloaFT0f71").split(",")
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    print(f"Uploading file: {temp_file.name} to Google Drive folder: {folder_id}")

    # Use media body directly for efficient upload from temporary file
    response = service.files().create(
        body={
            "name": remote_path.split("/")[-1],
            "parents": folder_id,
            "mimeType": "text/csv"  # Set MIME type for CSV files
        },
        media_body=temp_file
    ).execute()
    print(f"File uploaded successfully: {response['id']}")

def download_file_from_gcs(bucket, key):
  """
  Downloads a file from Cloud Storage and writes it to a temporary file.

  Args:
      bucket (str): Name of the Cloud Storage bucket.
      key (str): Name of the file in the bucket.

  Returns:
      str: Path to the downloaded file within the temporary location.
  """
  print(f"Downloading key: {key} in bucket: {bucket}")
  client = storage.Client()
  source_bucket = client.bucket(bucket)
  blob_object = source_bucket.blob(key)
  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
      blob_object.download_to_file(temp_file.name)
      local_path = temp_file.name  # Capture the temporary file path
  return local_path

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def drive_upload(cloud_event):
    data = cloud_event.data
    print("Full event data:", data)
    try:
        # Access bucket name assuming a nested structure
        bucket_name = data["bucket"]
        file_name = data["name"]
        print(f"File name extracted from event data: {file_name}")
        print(f"Bucket name extracted from event data: {bucket_name}")
    except KeyError:
        print("Bucket or file name not found in event data.")
        return  # Gracefully exit the function

    if file_name in ["Trials", "Control"]:
        try:
            # Credentials for Google Drive API access
            credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])
            # Downloading file from GCS with temporary file
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                local = download_file_from_gcs(bucket_name, file_name)
                print(f("Temp File Path: {local}"))
                # Uploading the file to drive
                upload_to_drive(temp_file, file_name, credentials)
                print(f'File {file_name} copied to Google Drive folder')
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```

However I keep getting these errors in the log

```
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/workspace/main.py", line 74, in drive_upload     local = download_file_from_gcs(bucket_name, file_name)
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/workspace/main.py", line 49, in download_file_from_gcs

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST blob_object.download_to_file(temp_file.name)

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1150, in download_to_file

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST self._prep_and_do_download(

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 4352, in _prep_and_do_download

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST self._do_download(

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1007, in _do_download

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST response = download.consume(transport, timeout=timeout)
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 237, in consume

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST return _request_helpers.wait_and_retry(
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_request_helpers.py", line 155, in wait_and_retry

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST response = func()
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST            ^^^^^^

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 233, in retriable_request

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST self._write_to_stream(result)

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 124, in _write_to_stream

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST  self._stream.write(chunk)
2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-03-17 23:18:25.996 SAST  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the code. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Python exceptions include line numbers to show which line of code failed. Your question does not include those details nor the source code with line numbers. Your code does not include the source code for `object has no attribute 'write'`

Comment: @JohnHanley the source code is given without line numbers. The errors given come from the source code above. And yes I'm aware the Python exceptions include the line of code that failed, hence why I'm asking others as to why it has because I'm stuck :)

Comment: Reread my comment and improve your question with the required details. For example, where in your code is `write` called? Your code does not include that section of code. Include complete stack traces and not parts.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's why I'm confused and have been stuck on this, the code I've provided is the entire source code without any missing pieces.